# Debugging GWT on tablets (Android, iPad)

Tags: ipad, debugging, gwt, tablet

We're running with a strange error running our GWT application on tablets (both iPad and Android). It's a touch event the one producing the error ("undefined is not an object")

How can you debug a GWT application for this scenario. We need to produce tablet touch events or run the GWT code on development mode in the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options that have helped us debug GWT apps on the iPad:

- a Windows machine with a touchscreen (we have [this one](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-1819&ST=Monitors%20Monitor%20Accessories&dgc=ST&cid=72662&lid=1838870&acd=s_pla_dhs:000011,,901pdb6671) at the office)
- Java logging + the popup log panel (or remote logging) ([Google Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging))
- [Firebug Lite](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/run-firebug-on-ipad-or-iphone/) - this may not help with this specific problem, but maybe in the future. :)

Hope some of these help.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can debug a compiled GWT application (works for me using GWT 2.4).

You need to have the GWT Developer Plugin installed in the tablet browser. I don't know if it's possible but if it is, all you need to do is append the `gwt.codesvr=<yourDevMachineIp>:<yourDevModePort>` query parameter to your app URL while running Dev Mode for your app in Eclipse.

**Disclaimer:** I've only tried this with a compiled app in a browser running on the same machine as my Eclipse IDE. If you're successful, please post a brief note here.

Comment: We already debug GWT on our desktops, the question is with the tablet's browser (android & iPad)

Comment: Of course. My premise here is that if you can install the GWT Developer browser plugin into Webkit/Safari on your Android/iPad respectively, you should be able to debug the compiled app.

Comment: You cannot install plugins in iOS Safari.